zmk-config git branch is head for new cargo projects in non-parent directory
Problem:
I have a zmk-config dir in ~/zmk-config, which is also a git repo. This repo seems to be the head of every new git repo I create, even in different/non-child dirs.
Ex:
~
-> pwd
/Users/uname

-> cd ~/zmk-config
zmk-config on branch zmk-config

-> git show 
commit a1... (HEAD -> zmk-config)
    
    trying to change head
...

-> cd ~/rust
/Users/uname/rust

-> cargo new vcs_test
building...

-> cd vcs_test
vcs_test on branch zmk-config
v1.78.0 -> 

I was expecting:
-> cd vcs_test
vcs_test on branch vcs_test

I have tried removing .git from both repos and re-initializing, but I still encounter the error when building a new rust project with cargo.
I have tried git reset in both repos, and that hasn't fixed the issue either.
Using cargo new vcs_test --vcs none does not fix the issue.
I am new/learning rust and cargo, and I know very little about git.
I am using starship terminal emulator, and my editor is helix with rust-analyzer LSP.
Thanks for any tips in advance. I am not sure where to start with troubleshooting this issue.
UPDATE: from directory ~/rust/vcs_test
v1.78.0 -> git config --list --show-origin
file:/opt/homebrew/etc/gitconfig        credential.helper=osxkeychain
file:/Users/james/.gitconfig      user.name=james
file:/Users/james/.gitconfig      user.email=james@gmail.com
file:/Users/james/.gitconfig      init.defaultbranch=zmk-config
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        core.precomposeunicode=true
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true

This shows that the init.defaultbranch=zmk-config directory is zmk-config. Does anyone have any tips to change this behavior?

Are you sure the .git directory is under ~/zmk-config/ and not under ~/?

Thank you for the comment. Yes, I am sure that the .git directory is under zmk-config.
On home ~/
-> cd .git gives no such file or directory.
On home ~/
-> cd ~/zmk-config/.git moves into the .git directory.

FIX:
-> git config init.defaultBrach master

-> cd ~/rust

~/rust
-> cargo new vcs_test
Building...

-> cd vcs_test

vcs on master
v1.78.0 -> git config --list --show-origin
... init.defaultbranch=master

